# GIT client for Linux with 2fa

Tags: linux, github, 2-factor-authentication

How can I work with GIT repositories under Linux (Debian and Ubuntu) if the repository enforces 2FA? It seems the command line GIT client does not have any support for this. GIT Desktop does not seem to be available for Linux. Are there Alternatives?

Note: I already tried to use "Personal Access Tokens" like described here ...

[Make “git pull/push/clone” work with two factor authentication](https://webkul.com/blog/github-push-with-two-factor-authentication/)

but on "git clone https://...git" I am, after entering my GIT username and the newly created token instead the password, still getting the error message

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

Comment: Can’t you use SSH keys?

Comment: I don't see any way to use SSH keys with the git command line tool either. Can you provide instructions how to?

Comment: See documentation for ssh here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: ... and use the SSH clone URL given in each project (`git@github.com:project/repository.git`).

Answer (score 2):

[The official GitHub command-line client](https://github.com/cli/cli) supports [browser-based logins](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login).

In practice, it’s common to use SSH keys instead of 2FA; see [the GitHub documentation on setting up SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), and then update your remote URIs to use SSH (`git@github.com:project/repository.git`).